# PHP Simple Dom - Loop through one class at a time?

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping, simpledom

Is there any way to do this? currently I'm using this method to go through the td's for every table in a wikipedia entry that have a class of wikitable.

```
foreach ($html->find('table.wikitable td') as $key => $info)
{
    $text = $info->innertext;
}
```

However, what I want to do is have seperate loops for each table that share the class name of wikitable. I can't figure out how to do this.

Is there some kind of syntax? I want to do something like this

```
$first_table = $html->find('table.wikitable td', 0); // return all the td's for the first table
$second_table = $html->find('table.wikitable td', 1); // second one
```

Comment: According to [their docs](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/#fragment-14) it looks like you should be able to use just the syntax you have...did that not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might not fully understand your question but it seems that `$html->find` simply returns an array, in your case an array of tables:

```
$tables = $html->find('table.wikitable');
```

You can then loop through your tables and find the td's in each table:

```
foreach( $tables as $table )
{
   $tds = $table->find('td');

   foreach( $tds as $td )
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

If you only want to target the second table you can use:

```
$table = $tables[1];
```

Or something like that.